# Tcl - Как при нажатии Enter применить процедуру к содержимому entry

Tags: tcl

```
entry  .entry   -textvar a
bind   .entry <Return> { -command {tk_messageBox  -title "Арабское в Римское " \
                         -message "Арабское $a  ==>  Римское [eval {Vvod $a}]" }} 
pack   .entry   -side left

proc Vvod {a} {
set u [format "%d" $a]
set q [expr $u * 2]
}
```

Просьба исправить код так, чтобы в результате его работы появлялось окно с текстом
(например, Арабское 9  ==>  Римское 18)

Answer (score 0):

```
entry  .entry   -textvar a
bind   .entry <Return> { tk_messageBox  -title "Арабское в Римское " \
                         -message "Арабское $a ==>  Римское [eval {Vvod $a}]" }
pack   .entry   -side left

proc Vvod {a} {
set u [format "%d" $a]
set q [expr $u * 2]
}
```